# Using an earthed function generator with an earthed oscilloscope and ground loops

Tags: signal, ground-loop

I have a function generator and I noticed that its DC GND is internally wired to its earth pin.

Similarly I have an oscilloscope and I noticed that its DC GND is also internally wired to its earth pin.

So now If I use this function generator with this oscilloscope(with 3-prong power cords) wouldn't there be a ground loop?

If so, should I use 2-prong power cable for one of the instrument to eliminate it as a solution?

**EDIT:** An illustration for the question:

[image]

On the left side the box represents the function generator, on the right side the box represents the oscilloscope.

Circles represent the BNC connectors.

Number 1 and 3 are analog grounds of the function generator and the scope.

Number 2 is the GND shield of the coax cable, where the coax cable is connected from function generator to the scope (i.e. function generator and scope GND are connected)

Number 4 is the earth wire

L, N, E are the line, neutral and earth pin of the 3-prong power cable.

Comment: Does it cause a problem when you hook the two together?

Comment: I dont know but I thought there must be a principle

Comment: If two sytems are earth grounded I mean

Comment: Currents tend to travel the path of least resistance.

Comment: How bout ground loops? Wouldnt they effect the measurement?

Comment: I edited my question and added an illustration. Do you agree there is a ground loop in this setup?Through 1 - 2 - 3 -4

Answer (score 2):

To measure high-voltage signals up to 40KV, we used 2 channels of the scope and 40KV probes connected to the device being tested. The scope inputs were grounded to earth gnd. In this case the signal ground was NOT used, as the voltages would have arced inside the oscilloscope and destroyed it.
 The 40KV probes divided the signal by 1,000 so it was within the limits the scope could read. The 2 channels were combined with software to yield a differential result, seeing only the signal across the 2 probes.
The same setup can be used to measure lower voltage waveforms without any ground-loop issues. Most scopes have a 50 volt signal limit but the probes that come with the scope normally have a x10 switch built in, allowing a maximum signal level of 500 volts without using special HV probes.
If the device being tested has a floating power supply, or you use a isolation transformer, then issues with ground loops go away.

Comment: I edited my question and added an illustration to make it more clelar. Do you agree there is a ground loop in this setup? Through 1 - 2 - 3 -4

Comment: @user16307. As you have drawn it, yes there is a loop, but the loop has no effect unless you induce a strong signal (high-current) into it. If each instrument has a gnd post, run a short piece of 14 awg wire between the 2 to minimize loops. Remember there is no current in this loop unless you inject it from a strong signal or power source. Your function generator by itself puts out only milliamps of current at most.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. In data acquisition systems these loops are serious issue.

Comment: I would consider buying a small isolation transformer for just the scope. I have used them myself for the reasons you just gave. Using an ungrounded plug can create a shock hazard unless you use a isolation transformer.

Comment: Using a scope or a function generator with ungrounded plugs  can create a shock hazard. I can understand that it is not very safe. But are there legal obligations to use them with earth grounded considerations in work places?

Comment: I have work in several manufacturing plants and as long as basic NEC codes were followed there was no issue, and I had to construct a lot of custom AC feeds myself. Ungrounded equipment should not be a shock hazard unless there is an internal short. If you use a isolation transformer, plug in the scope using an ungrounded connection, then measure the gnd - gnd voltage first. If very low then it is safe to measure the AC current leakage from the scope gnd to actual earth gnd at an AC outlet. Maximum allowed leakage is 100uA, or 50uA for medical grade equipment.

Comment: If other countries and standards are used, I have found that leakage can be as high as 250uA under certain condition. A general search of Wikipedia did not offer a chart or table of other types of limits.